# Exim Catch email and forward to address

Tags: email, exim, catch-all

I have dedicated server with many domains on it.
I want to catch all emails from specific addresses for any domain that means accepting all emails from `xxx@example.com` and forward it to a specific address.

I used, Exim on my server and cpanel.

I don't want a method to accept and forward on one account!